# Generate array values dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, date

I want to create a dynamic array that will look like this, using years:

```
array(2012,2011,2010,2009,2008,2007,2006,2005)
```

Basically I have the starting year which is constant, 2005, and I want the array to dynamically change each year, adding the new year. Currently, I grab the current year via:

```
$this_year = date('Y');
```

Is there some easy way to generate the array using the two known years, the constant **2005** and the **current year**?

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: [This search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+create+an+array+of+years&submit=search) returns some related questions which would have helped you as well.

Comment: I was thinking more in terms of sequential numbers as oppose to years, I guess it's obvious that people would have tried this before specifically for years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$years = range(CONSTANT_YEAR, date('Y'));`

Comment: Thanks, figured it was easy. Lol, took me way to long to realize this generates an `array` and that I don't have to do `array($years)`.. it's getting late, long day :)

Answer (score 1):

Here it is http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php
$years = range(2005,date('Y'));

Comment: Just curious, what is the point of the `(int)`? Does it need it?

Comment: `date()` returns a string, `range()` takes mixed; thus no conversion needed.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
$this_year = date("Y");
$years_array = array();
for ($i == 2005; $i < $this_year; $i++) {
array_push($years_array,$i);
}
print_r $years_array;
```

You use a for cycle that starts in 2005 and stops in current year, for each year it will add it to the end of the array, I haven't tested it but it should work